# Testing the separation of two AD domains

Tags: active-directory, migration

We are currently working on a so called carve-out project, i.e. part of a larger company OLDCO got sold separately and the new entity builds up a new Active Directory domain NEWCO. During the transition phase both the OLDCO domain controllers as well as the NEWCO domain controllers as well as the clients share in IP address space. The NEWCO domain trusts the OLDCO domain for the time being, so one can for example authenticate to a NEWCO client machine using an OLDCO user account.

Obviously by the end of the transition phase the OLDCO AD will be gone, possibly by separation of networks which will take place only in some remote future.

We are now looking for a way to make sure we can test applications for their dependency to OLDCO. I.e. if we have moved application X to new servers which are domain members of NEWCO how can we make sure we do not use any OLDCO resources anymore without possibly noticing.

We thought of implementing some firewall rules which can be easily switched on and off which would temporarily prevent any access to the OLDCO comain controllers from any migrated application servers as the best simulation of "no longer there", but would that be a valid test?

Not being too sure about AD internals, for example, I have no idea if NEWCO domain controllers would possibly cache any data from the OLDCO domain as long as the trust is there and that cache might expire at a point in time where the OLDCO DCs will have been gone and problems will hit us long time after testing that looked successful.

Has anyone successfully done a project like that before and possibly any other idea how to simulate such as carve-out in an AD forest?

Comment: Domain Controllers do not cache logon data from other domains.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Standard, non-Read Only Domain Controllers do not contain the caching you are worried about. Only properly integrated domain controllers existing within a replication topology cache information about each other, such as Up-to-Date Vectors (UTDVs) and other NTDS specifics which can be seen using `ntdsutil`.

If it is North-South traffic (internal-external) traffic you're testing I would consider testing using firewall rules to simulate disconnection from the resources in question.

If it is East-West traffic (internal-internal) traffic you're testing I would consider enabling Advanced Audit Policies on the domain controller using Group Policy Objects (GPOs). You're most interested in the `Audit account logon events` and `Audit logon events` settings available under `Computer Configuration\Policies\Windows Settings\Security Settings\Local Policies\Audit Policy`. Your GPO should be linked with Security Filtering against the BUILTIN Domain Controllers group.

You can then gather Event Viewer events of the following IDs:

- **Audit Logon Events:** 4624, 4625, 4648, 4634, 4647, 4672, and 4778.
- **Audit Account Logon Events:** 4678, 4679, 4770, 4771, 4774, and 4776.

I'm providing a PowerShell snippet you can run locally (as Administrator) on the domain controllers in question for all matching events in the last twelve (12) hours:

`Get-EventLog -LogName Security -After ((Get-Date).AddHours(-12)) | Where-Object { $_.EventId -in 4624, 4625, 4648, 4634, 4647, 4672, 4678, 4679, 4770, 4771, 4774, 4776, 4778 } | Select TimeWritten, Source, EventID, InstancedId, Message | Sort TimeWritten -Descending | Format-Table Auto`

Answer (score 1):

It’s a complex move.

Activate successful account logon auditing into your OLDCO Domain Controler. In the security log you will see all login attempt made against the DC after, thus at the end you will see if something still authenticate against it, as the credential are not cached from your NEWCO Domain Controller.

Be advised it can create a lot of log. Be sure to have a big C or to move the log somewhere else.

For such move you have multiple things to think too;

- If you use Exchange you might endup using linked mailbox for the migration. Start ready for that.
- SQL instance need to be tested if you are using windows authentification, as all user information for the logging will not fit newco domain. To test that part it’s easier to bring another sql server online on the newco and migrate the data to test out if your application still work good outside of production.
- For file ressources you will have to check the security group for each folder to replicate it. As old security group defined into the share will no longer work when the oldco domain will fall.
- Do you use radius or a certificate server? etc...

As you can see you have a lot of documentations to do to plan your move correctly.

Comment: Sorry, but maybe my question was not phrased well. I was not asking what I have to consider but how I will be able to test my migration once I think I am done. Did this not become clear from my wording?

Comment: @TorstenS Sorry mistead then, will update  my answer.